# Java Scanner nextInt() make me hit enter twice for the value to be accepted

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

```
package ex3.io.excape;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Prg {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    int a;
    System.out.print("a : ");
    a=scan.nextInt();

    System.out.println(a);
}
}
```

The result is following:

```
a : 3

3
```

To get this result, I had to hit enter twice.
How can I get the result without the extra line in the middle and only hit enter once?

I tried

```
a=Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());
```

or

```
a=scan.nextInt();
scan.nextLine();
```

But it did not work...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I just ran it, and it only required a single return.

Comment: Yes you shouldn't need to return twice. Are you sure this is the exact code you're using?

Comment: Ahhhh I just restarted my eclipse and cleared other java files. Thank you for check for me, thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it's took only 1 enter. I don't know why this taking 2 enter from you. Therefore, I made some basic changes in the code. Just run this and check this out if it is just a error from your compiler.

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    int a;
    System.out.print("Enter a value of a: ");
    a=scan.nextInt();

    System.out.println("The value of a is: " +a);
```